# I do not receive FCM Push Notifications with the application closed. Ionic 3 and Angular

Tags: node.js, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

Good day folks, it is my first publication on the site, I apologize if I do not comply with all the publication rules because I do not know them in detail.

Step to comment my problem .. I have an app made with ionic 3 and angular, which works with notifications between users to emerge an action, investigate the firebase forums and several other places and tried several codes but I could not fix it. The application sends data and notification to a specific token, the device registered by the token receives the data but not the notification. Not when it is with the application open, or when it is in the background or closed. This is the code you use:

**1) To receive the token**

```
 this.fcm.getToken (). then (token => {

         alert ('token' + JSON.stringify (token))

         // Here I save the token I receive from the device
      })
```

This works .. I can get the device token.

**2) To receive the notification:**

```
this.fcm.onNotification (). subscribe (data => {
        if (data.wasTapped) {
          alert ("Received in background")
        } else {
          alert ("Received in foreground")
        };
      })
```

This also works, **when I sent a notification from the firebase console I get it perfectly** .. the problem is when I sent it from the server

**3) Code for notification:**

```
SendNotific ()
{
let keytoken = 'fqN5yelN7gk: APA91bGT0 ......'
let keyserver = 'AAAA4oCrTNk: APA91bHLBWcyQimF ....'
let headers = {'Authorization': 'key =' + keyserver,
'Content-Type': 'application / json'};
let url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
let body = {
"notification":{
"title": "notification title",
"body": "notification body"
},
"data":{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2"
},
"to": keytoken,
"priority": "high",
"content_available": true
}

this.http.post (url, body, headers) .then (data =>
{
alert (JSON.stringify (data))

}). then (error => {
alert ('error' + JSON.stringify (error))
})
}
```

**If the application is in the foreground of the device**, the alert becomes visible, that is, I receive the data that I sent in "Data". (For this case it would be "key1" and "key2") but I do not receive any notification. **If the application is in the background or closed**, no notification is shown, and when I open the app again the alert messages are shown with the "Data" that arrived.

As I said before, **if you sent a notification from the Firebase console it works perfectly ..**

Clearly I'm missing some data that I can not find .. I saw several publications that talk about the same thing but I can not give the solution ..

Will I be missing specific data within the notification so it can be visible?

Does the user need to accept any permission to receive the notification?

Thank you very much and sorry if I could not explain clearly

regards,

Julian.

Answer (score 0):

So, the first thing I note in your code is that `Sender` is missing from `headers`.
headers should be something like:

```
let headers = {
               'Authorization': 'key=' + keyserver,
               'Content-Type': 'application / json',
               'Sender': 'id=' + senderId
              };
```

The body will have a `to` or `token` for the `device token` i.e., the recipient. So, the body will be something like:

```
let body = {
  "token": keytoken,
  "notification":{
    "title": "notification title",
    "body": "notification body"
  },
  "data":{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true
}
```

And, I think you wanted to promisify `http` and catch the error in `http.post`. In that case, the code should look something like:

```
this.http.post(url, body, headers).toPromise().then(data =>
{
  alert (JSON.stringify(data));
}).catch( error => {
  alert ('error' + JSON.stringify (error));
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, try and it does not work. Add sender id to headers. I do not solve my problem and did not break anything
Also change "to" to "token" and it does not work. If I make this change, the "data" does not arrive either.

Comment: Just one more clarification: are you saying that you received the push notification perfectly in the device when the app was in background (and even closed) when you sent the notification using console, but didn't when you sent it from server?

Comment: Exactly, when I send from the testing console https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com/ or from the console of firebase works correctly.
My problem is when I send the notification from the server, clearly my error is in the json I sent.     

I clarify: When I send the notification the function this.http.post () works correctly. If I have the application in the foreground I receive the data that I send within the "data" parameter. If the application is in the background or closed nothing happens until I open the app manually, when I open it I receive the data I send but not the notification.

Comment: Within the function:

this.fcm.onNotification (). subscribe (data => {
        if (data.wasTapped) {
          alert ("Received in background")
        } else {
          alert ("Received in foreground")
        };
      })

The "WasTapped" data always arrives in false

Comment: WasTapped will be false, that is expected.. You need to add `"click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"`
Check https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm#send-notification-payload-example-rest-api

Comment: You receive the notifications when you open the app, but the platform can't handle displaying the notifications, or the app somehow the app's registration is lost which is unlikely as it works from firebase console.
Remove the spaces from token i.e., the device registration ID and add the icon field before trying again.

Comment: If the above doesn't work, then you should try it on a different device and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try what you suggest
Previously I had been recommended to add "click_action" but it does not work for me.
I will continue testing and commenting on my results.
I previously referred to WasTapped because when I have the app in the background and I get a notification from the tester, WasTapped arrives in TRUE.
I will do tests and upload with images, thanks for your help